# Magento 1.9 disable plugin for specific ip

Tags: magento, plugins, module, magento-1.9

I've got a Magento store (1.9) with a very simple plugin. It changes the customer group when someone places an order in a website. But we also work with a POS.

In the POS the plugin is also trying to change the customer group but it gives an error.

So what I want to do is disable the plugin for our local IP (or User).

The code is the following or check [Github](https://github.com/RolfvdH/Magento-Automatic-Group-Change):

observer.php

```
     <?php
    class RvdH_GroupChange_Model_Observer
    {
public function changeGroup(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    /*$event = $observer->getEvent(); //Fetches the current event"
    $customer = $event->getCustomer();
    $dbcustomer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer[entity_id]);*/
    // ensure it's not guest checkout
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $customer->setGroupId(5);
        $customer->save();

    }
}
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

  <modules>
    <RvdH_GroupChange>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </RvdH_GroupChange>
  </modules>

  <global>
    <models>
      <RvdH_GroupChange>
        <class>RvdH_GroupChange_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </RvdH_GroupChange>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <RvdH_GroupChange>
                <class>RvdH_GroupChange_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>changeGroup</method>
            </RvdH_GroupChange>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: why not to include this in plugin function, only get IP of visitor and then make condition?You can obtain IP of customer from session:  $customer_ip = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I just had to change the `<global>` tag to `<frontend>` in the config.xml.
Now it only works in frontend and not global.